# display items in a 'row'

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML + CSS and I do not understand the following thing:

If my code looks like following, then the display would be like this:
CSS:

```
 .col-sm-4 {
     width: 24%;
    float:right;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.Row {
    border: 3px solid #57b1dc;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="Row">
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:
[image]

However, when I apply class `.col-sm-4` to all my `div` elements, then suddenly border shifts like this:

[image]

To me, it looks like all my elements are no longer part of the main div item.

Why do I need this:

I have found bootstrapper and I try to understand the concept of nicely laying out items in the document (in this way, there are 4 columns in a row)

Comment: Floats are out-of-flow.

Comment: This article may help you understand the `float` property a little better: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:KY_rhrm6P9kJ:www.cssnewbie.com/css-float-property/+&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: Oriol has redirected me to the correct answer. Thank you all